# How can I remove Azure QuickStart templates after temporary evaluation?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I want to test out the Azure QuickStart Template for PCI-DSS, which is currently under evaluation by Azure:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/pci-paas-webapp-ase-sqldb-appgateway-keyvault-oms

However, I'm weary of doing a quick start deployment after a nightmare with AWS Quickstart. I forgot to delete each of the components and wound up getting charged hundreds of dollars (which is my fault) - but even after I realized I left it up, it was a total nightmare to get it deleted and I had to contact Customer Support several times to get them to remove it.

I have the Visual Studio Dev Essentials $200 credit, as well as the $25 I received at registration time, so let's consider $225 to be my budget. I contacted the developers of that template and they estimated that it would be about $15-20 per day, which is fine with me.

So here's my question: **Is there a way to automate this deployment and scale it back / remove it after I am done evaluating the environment?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways of doing so, but you don't really need that, just delete the resource group you deployed resources into, that will get rid of every single resource you deployed with that template, so no more costs.

Resource group is a concept in Azure, like a logical grouping for your resources. You can delete it with a click from the portal and various automation options, like powershell:

```
Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name xxx
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!